# Regex after a special character in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex in java to get a specific output from a list of rooms at my University.

A outtake from the list looks like this:

- (A55:G260) Laboratorium 260
- (A55:G292) Grupperom 292
- (A55:G316) Grupperom 316
- (A55:G366) Grupperom 366
- (HDS:FLØYEN) Fløyen (appendix)
- (ODO:PC-STUE) Pulpakammeret (PC-stue)
- (SALEM:KONF) Konferanserom

I want to get the value that comes between the colon and the parenthesis.

The regex I am using at the moment is:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[:]([A-Za-z0-9ÆØÅæøå-]+)");
matcher = pattern.matcher(room.text());
```

I've included ÆØÅ, because some of the rooms have Norwegian letters in them.

Unfortunately the regex includes the building code also (e.g. "A55") in the output... Comes out like this:

```
A55
A55
A55
:G260
:G292
:G316
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: in what output? you're only showing the regular expression, but how you actually use matcher to retrieve the results? add that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not your regular expression. You need to reference group(`1`) for the match result.

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

However, you may consider using a negated character class instead.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(":([^)]+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(HDS:FLØYEN) Fløyen (appendix)";
    // select everything after ":" upto the first ")" and replace the entire regex with the selcted data
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?:(.*?)\\).*", "$1"));
    String s1 = "ODO:PC-STUE) Pulpakammeret (PC-stue)";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(".*?:(.*?)\\).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
FLØYEN
PC-STUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with `String` Opreations as follows,

```
String val = "(HDS:FLØYEN) Fløyen (appendix)";

if(val.contains(":")){

    String valSub = val.split("\\s")[0];
    System.out.println(valSub);

    valSub = valSub.substring(1, valSub.length()-1);

    String valA = valSub.split(":")[0];
    String valB = valSub.split(":")[1];

    System.out.println(valA);
    System.out.println(valB);

}
```

Output :

```
(HDS:FLØYEN)
HDS
FLØYEN
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class test
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

```
  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "(HDS:FLØYEN) Fløyen (appendix)";
  String pattern = ":([^)]+)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

}
}